# Recovery mode not working

Tags: boot, 16.04

When I boot my computer none of the dispay options pull up and I can't even open a terminal using Ctl+Alt+T. When I try to boot it in recovery mode it the same thing happens. I don't get the normal option menu that comes in recovery mode. I was trying to upgrade to 16.04 and halfway through the upgrade my computer turned off, that's when this started happening.

Comment: I also get a message in the recovery mode that it failed to start Load Kernel Modules.

Comment: Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS to fix the kernel loading error message. Can you get to the GRUB menu? Can you get to the login screen? Exactly what do you see?

Comment: I get the grub menu and the login screen is normal, just as always, but after I log in, there's just a blank screen and nothing but the background

Answer (score 1):

## step #1

- turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS, to fix "kernel module load" errors.
- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose `Advanced Options`
- choose `Recovery mode`
- choose `dpkg - fix broken packages`
- let it try to finish the aborted upgrade

If that doesn't resolve your problem, I'll give you a different set of specific commands to execute. Report back.

## step #2 (detail pending)

```
sudo apt-get update

dpkg --configure -a

apt-get install -f
```

Comment: In the grub command screen when I enter that code it says "can't find command dpkg".

Comment: Also, I don't seem to be able to disable secure boot

Comment: Like I said, I don't get the normal advanced options. All it gives me is the option to boot in recovery mode or normal and recovery mode doesn't do anything.

Comment: `Secure boot` is a function of the BIOS, and happens long before even the GRUB menu, so the setting has got to be there somewhere. If you have a tabbed BIOS interface, look for a security tab. What happens if you choose a recovery mode for a prior kernel? Does it give you a normal full recovery menu of options, to include dpkg and root? What happens if you just try to boot normally but into a prior kernel? I'm looking for some options here. If we can't get to anything, you may just have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I know where the secure boot is, but for some reason it isn't giving me the option to turn it on or off, it just has it enabled and won't let me change it. As far as kernels go, I only have one option. The only one that shows up is Linux 4.2.0-38-generic and the recovery mode for that

Comment: Some BIOS makes it difficult to change this setting. They sometimes have another layer of menus that you have to traverse to get to where you can actually change the setting. Keep looking. You'll need to find it to get past the kernel module load error. At this point, I'd just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: If I reinstall Ubuntu from a flash drive will I lose all my files?

Comment: First, I'd always recommend backing up your files first. You've been warned. If you install from a DVD or USB, just tell the installer to install into the same partition where Ubuntu was installed before, but UNCHECK the FORMAT PARTITION option, and I'll keep your existing HOME folder.